# How to make common notification function for a app in quasar Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using quasar framework with Vue 3. In App i writtern a function for notification in all pages

```
const $q = useQuasar()

const positivemsg = function (msg){
  $q.notify({
    type: 'positive',
    message: msg,
    position:'top-right',
    timeout:800
  })
}
```

To call this function i use

```
positivemsg(msg)
```

Where i can i write this function to get in all pages to make app easy?

TIA

Comment: You can try creating a Notification or an Alert component and just import it in the pages you need it. OR you can also create a Layout component and import it there.

Comment: The most logical place is to put this function inside `App.vue` and subscribe it for a message on your global message bus (mitt). Then every time you need to show a notification from anywhere in your app - you will emit the event on the global message bus with your message as an argument. You may also provide an options argument for the Quasar Notify function.

Comment: Can explain in detail